# PPQN in a 16 Step Sequencer vs DAW?

Tags: midi, daw

I was wondering if the [PPQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulses_per_quarter_note) in a 16 step sequencer is 4? Since there's 4 divisions per quarter note?

[image: sequencer]

In comparison in a DAW like Logic, I read the PPQN is 960. So in a measure there'd be 960*4 = 3840 steps. So a 3840 step sequencer (versus 16 step sequencer). So a midi track in a DAW is like a sequencer but with greater PPQN (more steps)?

Comment: In 4/4 time. In 3/4 time would it be 960*3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

<sup>Not sure what else I can say…</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "16 step sequencer"? There's hardware 16 steps sequencer (eurorack stuff, drum machines, external sequencers) where you can select the pulse other than 4PPQN, to be compatible with hardware that have another PPQN value.

PPQN can be relative measurement unit for int/ext sync signals, and it can be a "event time resolution", too. 4PPQN resolution is suitable for generic hardware "very-oldschool" 16-step sequencers. If you want to use note-on's and note-off's shorter than 16-th notes and even 8-th etc... triplets - you have to stick with bigger PPQN resolutions. I believe that 960PPQN is pretty big resolution which doesn't impact on listeners or performers experience at all.

Comment: I just meant 16 step sequencer like my korg volcas. I was wondering if they were 4ppqn.